# How to turn off WhatsApp incoming message sound in Redmi Prime 2 / MIUI 7.1?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, miui

I've turned it off in

- Setting > Notifications > App Notifications > Whatsapp > Sound & vibration
- Whatsapp > Settings > Notifications > Conversation Tones

And it still sounds. At one point I even tried to turn off all WhatsApp notif, but it STILL sounds even when no notification shown.

I just recently noticed this because usually I put my phone in Silent Mode. But now I'm waiting for a phone call, I can't do that, and suddenly noted how annoying this thing is.

Answer (score 1):

One of the sound to play in the whatsapp settings is Silent. That should work and leave notifications still appearing. 
Indeed extremely quitr confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Download 1 second silent audio from the internet and set that as you message tone.

Link: http://www.minidisc.org/charman/downloads.html